# How to use torsocks with python urllib3 and along a domain name where ipv6 is availaible ? Or rather disable ɪᴘᴠ6 in that case?

Tags: torsocks, dns, ipv6, torify

Simply trying to access en.wikipedia.org with a python script where a huge stack of dependencies prevents configuring a proxy (would take a year in order to rewrite dependencies for getting proxy support especially since some of the dependencies like https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/ or https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/ don’t support socks proxies).

So I thought I could use `torsocks/torify` but :

```
1652642569 ERROR torsocks[327]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)
2022-05-15 21:22:49,723 - BatchWorkExecutor [ERROR] - An exception occurred while executing work_handler.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/pypy3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib64/pypy3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
_socket.gaierror: [Errno -4] Non-recoverable failure in name resolution
```

This means an ɪᴘv6 address is being attempted to be written in the space for an ɪᴘv4 address and can be reproduced with curl :

```
$ torify curl https://rpc.ethermine.org
1653212429 ERROR torsocks[599]: [socks5] Resolve destination buffer too small (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:701)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: rpc.ethermine.org
```

How to prevent torsocks from receiving an ɪᴘv6 address on name resolution ? Is it possible to configure tor to not only disable ɪᴘv6 connectivity, but ɪᴘv6 name resolution too ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use torsocks with python then you can use the python-requests library, first of all, start the tor service in your background.
Then use this sort of script -:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {"http": "socks5h://localhost:9050", "https": "socks5h://localhost:9050"}
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
response = session.get(url)
```

And this code will help you to achieve what you want. I guess this is all what you need for now!

Comment: **Wrong answer !** I wrote `with a python script where a huge stack of dependencies prevents configuring a proxy (would take a year in order to rewrite dependencies for getting proxy support)`.  which means this is the dependencies which perform the various ʜᴛᴛᴘ calls directly. It can’t be changed without extensive work which would be cleared at each update.

Comment: TBH I still didn't understand what you are trying to do? What is your final goal to achieve?

Comment: I’m using a project which uses things like the `web3py` pip packages as well as several WebSockets which don’t support proxying and thus tor. Proxy support can’t be added to the code without involving a huge amount of work which would take nearly a year. **Thus torsocks is required for wrapping connections to ᴛᴏʀ**, but it doesn’t support resvolving domain names where ɪᴘv6 is available.

Comment: And https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/ is one of the components out of many you won’t be able to configure with tor.